# Application not returning from sl_RecvFrom

Tags: c, udp, microcontroller

I'm using UDP in order to get the current time from an ntp server.

Everything seems okay until the time when I'm expecting an response from the server. So I have two methods, the first one which sends the request to the ntp server and the second one which receives the response. I have no problem with the first one but in the second one, I am struggling with the sl_RecvFRom function because the application never returns from it.

I'll add here the code of this two functions.

```
 static returnTypes_t bsdUdpServer( uint16_t AddrSize){

      int16_t Status = (int16_t) ZERO;

      SockID = sl_Socket(SL_AF_INET,SL_SOCK_DGRAM, (uint32_t) ZERO);
      if (SockID < 0){
          printf("error on sl_Socket\n\r");
          return SOCKET_ERROR;
      }

      Status = sl_Bind(SockID, (SlSockAddr_t *) &LocalAddr, AddrSize);
      if (Status < 0){
          printf("problem on sl_Bind\n\r");
          return SOCKET_ERROR;
      }

      Status = sl_RecvFrom(SockID, packetBuffer, NTP_PACKET_SIZE * sizeof(uint8_t), (uint32_t) ZERO, (SlSockAddr_t *) &Addr, &AddrSize);
      if (Status < (int16_t) ZERO){
           printf("error - no bytes received: %d\n\r", (int16_t)Status);
           return SOCKET_ERROR;
      }

      Status = sl_Close(SockID);
      if (Status < 0)
           printf("problem on sl_Close\n\r");

      uint16_t highWord = index3 << 16 | index2;
      uint16_t lowWord = index1 << 16 | index0;

      uint32_t secondsSince1900 = highWord << 16 | lowWord;

      printf("Seconds since 1 Janeiro de 1900: %ld\n\r", secondsSince1900);

      return (STATUS_OK);

 }

 static returnTypes_t bsdUdpClient(uint16_t AddrSize) {

     int16_t Status = (int16_t) ZERO;

     memset(packetBuffer, 0, NTP_PACKET_SIZE);

     packetBuffer[0] = 0xE3; //0b11100011;   // LI, Version, Mode
     packetBuffer[1] = 0x00;     // Stratum, or type of clock
     packetBuffer[2] = 0x06;     // Polling Interval
     packetBuffer[3] = 0xEC;  // Peer Clock Precision
     // 8 bytes of zero for Root Delay & Root Dispersion
     packetBuffer[12]  = 49;
     packetBuffer[13]  = 0x4E;
     packetBuffer[14]  = 49;
     packetBuffer[15]  = 52;

     SockID = sl_Socket(SL_AF_INET, SL_SOCK_DGRAM, (uint32_t) ZERO);
     if (SockID < (int16_t) ZERO)
          return (SOCKET_ERROR);

     Status = sl_SendTo(SockID, packetBuffer, NTP_PACKET_SIZE * sizeof(uint8_t), (uint32_t) ZERO, (SlSockAddr_t *) &Addr, AddrSize);
     if (Status <= (int16_t) ZERO) {
          Status = sl_Close(SockID);
          if (Status < 0)
                return (SEND_ERROR);
          return (SEND_ERROR);
    }

    Status = sl_Close(SockID);
    if (Status < 0)
          return (SEND_ERROR);

    return (STATUS_OK);
}
```

Comment: do you run both methods in the same thread?

Comment: Yes @Jean-FrançoisFabre, I have a kind of main function where I call both methods.

Comment: How can I fix it @Jean-FrançoisFabre? Do I need to implement them in two different tasks?

Comment: my bad. Bad analysis from me. You send and then you wait for the server to reply. If it doesn't reply, you are stuck in your receive call. Are you sure that the server replies?

Comment: I don't. However, I've tried to ping the server from my terminal and I got answer from it. Nevertheless, I've tried a couple of different ones and I always get the same result. @Jean-FrançoisFabre

Comment: When you say I wait for the server to reply, do you mean that I need to  add explicitly a kind of delay after calling the bsdUdpClient() and before calling  bsdUdpServer()? @Jean-FrançoisFabre

Comment: no. The request you send to the external server does not get any reply. Can you test this ntp server by other means?

Comment: Yes, I understand what might be causing the problem. At the moment, I don't see how I can test the ntp server but I will try to figure out. Thanks @Jean-FrançoisFabre

Comment: When posting a question of the type: `why does my code not work?` post code that cleanly compiles, and still shows the error.  Otherwise there is little that we can do but guess as to the root of the problem.   Suggest also posting information on the environment.  The function names hint that the environment is a T.I. dsp, but that is not confirmed

Comment: Thanks for the advice @user3629249